# Marsden Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Any suggestions for a companion book/study guide to Marsden's analysis?
My analysis course is using it as a textbook but I feel as if it is rather dense. The professor does not really explain the material well.

Comment: you mean the book *Elementary classical analysis* of Marsden?

Comment: Yes Elementary Classical Analysis by Marsden

Answer (score 1):

It could be  comment, but I want to elevate it to a post. There are dozens of books out there in analysis, and there are two that I think is a good fit for some one like you:

1. Intro to analysis by David Brannan: This book explains the big and small pieces of info in the book.
2. Intro to real analysis by Kenneth Ross. This is a old but really good book.

You should attend class and read books to progress in the course. Reading book alone is not enough. Meet the Prof in his office to ask questions that you failed to understand....

Comment: Is it A First Course in Mathematical Analysis - DAVID ALEXANDER BRANNAN  Deepsea  ?

Comment: Thanks, I do have a copy of Ross and Ruding which I have been using to supplement. What I was looking more was for a guide that followed that which was being taught in Marsden. Unfortunately, I have really tried to go to class and to office hours multiple times. This is a visiting professor from another country and he doesn't speak english well at all so there is this huge communication barrier.

Answer (score 0):

Marsden's book is too broad and generalized (in comparison with many others books of analysis), and it seems that focuses in calculus a bit more than what I've seen in other analysis books.

To cover the same material that is in the Marsden's book you will need more than one book. By example try to see if the two volumes of *Mathematical analysis* of Zorich fit well for you, they covers almost the same material.

Or ask to your professor about what chapters of Marsden's book you will learn in the course, and then search for a book that covers these topics and fit your needs.